# DNS not resolving outside intranet

Tags: dns, iis-7.5

We are installing a security camera system in our company which comes with a DVR that hosts a website on which you can view the cameras via the web.

I have setup the DVR with a static IP of 192.168.120.199 on our network and can view the website while on our network (either when at work or logged in via VPN).  The camera DVR uses port 80 for viewing the webpage and port 9000 for Media Port.

We use GoDaddy to host our DNS info and I have added an Host(A) record of 'cameras' that points to the address of our server.  I have also added a forward lookup Host(A) to our domain's DNS manager of 'cameras' that points to 192.168.120.199.  When I use the address 'cameras.mysite.com' within our domain the website displays properly, but when I try the same address from outside our domain (ie, at home) it displays the default IIS 7 page (from our domain server).

Two questions about this setup:

- Why does the forward lookup work when inside our domain but not outside (why does it go to the IIS default page when outside the network)?
- How do I get this to forward correctly if not via the forward lookup host?

Answer (score 0):

Because internally you're looking it up on your internal DNS server and you get the right 192.168.x.x machine. When you look it up externally GoDaddy is giving you back the 192.168.x.x, but that's not a publicly routable IP, so doesn't go anywhere. If you really want to be able to connect to your security cameras from outside your facility then I suggest setting up a VPN for security reasons. But if you want GoDaddy to directly route to your internal machine from the public internet then you'll have to give it a publicly routable IP.

As a further note on that - 10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x and 172.16-31.255.255 are not publicly routable. They're called [private](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) IP blocks.